# (supervised ML) approach for time series segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, timeseries-segmentation

**Update prior to posting**

*So I had just finished writing my post and got suggested "time series segmentation" for my tags. Then I looked it up and it seems like it is the thing I need to do. I did some reading just now and found some options such as [Hidden Markov Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-series_segmentation#Hidden_Markov_Models) as well as a python toolbox ([seglearn](https://dmbee.github.io/seglearn/user_guide.html)) that seems like it can do what I need. I decided to still post this to get some input, especially since there seems to be a couple of approaches to this analysis and I am not sure which would suit my case best. Thank you!*

**My original Post**

Dear community

I have body (body-parts-in-space-coordinates and joint-angles) data while people are walking and I would like to design an algorithm that automatically detects and extracts (returns the timepoints of) step-cycles (i.e., the start to end time points of people making a step with a given leg - the full time series has multiple steps in addition to people turning to walk back etc.).

Here is an Example plot:
[image: Example 1]

For example, let's imagine I would like to extract the time window of the box labelled "step" in the top panel (it is a bit more complicated in reality but considering only the simple example will be enough for now)

I already developed an algorithm (using gradients and amplitude % criteria) that works if the data look similar to our example. However, since we also have patient data, signals, and the step cycles within them can look quite different to one another. For example, consider this time series:
[image: Example 2]

My algorithm breaks for such data. I was considering a supervised ML approach, something like:

1. Train on full time series with step-cycle time-windows being labelled as classes of interest.
2. Test on unknown time series and asking the model to return time-windows of where it predicts step cycles to have occurred.
3. Compare to human performance (at the moment, people manually select step cycle time windows by hand)

I have been googling for some days and found quite some time series classification approaches and toolboxes (such as [sktime](http://www.sktime.net/en/latest/) for example) but I felt like people are mostly interested in forecasting with time series ML.

Also - I should add that our dataset has probably 3-6 features that will likely be useful for the algorithm to classify this (and as mentioned before the "real" classification problem is a bit more complex than just the "single bump pattern" of the blue time series of my earlier example - e.g., step cycles as well as time series themselves vary in duration)

It would be great if any of you have any ideas or could point me to some keywords/papers. It really does not seem too difficult of a classification problem and it bugs me that I wasn't able to find anything about it thus far. So thank you very much for your help, I really do appreciate it.